# What's the simplest way to filter a list of objects based on what is on another list?

Tags: javascript

I have written too many lines to compare and then filter a list of objects based on what's in both. How can I simplify it?

```
const list1 = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Marie' }, { name: 'Carl' }, ]

const list2 = [{ firstName: 'John' }, { firstName: 'Peter' }, { firstName: 'Carl' }, ]
```

Desired result: `[{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Carl' }]`

Note: get objects from `list1` in which the key is `name`.

Comment: So filter and some

Answer (score 1):

For this use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Filter for every object from arr1 where for at least one element of arr2 the name  is equal to the firstName.

```js
const list1 = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Marie' }, { name: 'Carl' }, ]
const list2 = [{ firstName: 'John' }, { firstName: 'Peter' }, { firstName: 'Carl' }, ]

let res = list1.filter(({name}) => list2.some(({firstName}) => name==firstName));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this, for each item in list1, check if the item is present in list2 using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const list1 = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Marie' }, { name: 'Carl' }, ];
const list2 = [{ firstName: 'John' }, { firstName: 'Peter' }, { firstName: 'Carl' },];

let result = list1.filter(el => list2.find(el2 => el2.firstName === el.name));
console.log("Common items", result);
```